# Command line disable NetBIOS (SMB1 port 445)?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, netbios

I have an ethernet adapter and a wireless adapter and can't for the life of me figure out the command line (or powershell) used to disable Netbios over TCP/IP for all the adapters on a system.  I would appreciate any input on this.

[image]

Comment: You might get a better response on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: This is a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not for ServerFault (or StackOverflow). On second thought, it's actually a question for Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Andre Viot's blog:

```
$adapters=(gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration )
Foreach ($adapter in $adapters){
  Write-Host $adapter
  $adapter.settcpipnetbios(0)
}
```

> **Note** that you may need to press enter two times after pasting above, which
> confirms you're done commanding.

Should disable Netbios on EVERY adapter.  You might wish to be more discerning, and be sure you're disabling Netbios on the right interface, however, so I would first, to see a list of your adapters which are currently connected, run:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where IPAddress
```

Or for older PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $null }
```

```
ServiceName      DHCPEnabled     Index     Description               
-----------      -----------     -----     -----------               
VMSMP            True            14        Intel Wireless Adapter
VMSMP            True            29        Intel Ethernet Adapter
```

Select the one you want to disable using a filter provided to Where Object, like this.  I want to turn off NetBios on my LAN.

```
$adapter = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where Description -like "*Ethernet*" 
$adapter.SetTcpIPNetbios(0) | Select ReturnValue

ReturnValue
-----------
          0
```

There are a number of possible return codes though, like a WHOLE lot.  Make sure to [check the list here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and do not lazily assume that the function will work on every device.  You should definitely test this first and understand the ramifications.

http://www.alexandreviot.net/2014/10/09/powershell-disable-netbios-interface/

Comment: `SetTcpipNetbios(0)` == enable NetBIOS via DHCP. `SetTcpNetbios(2)` disables it. Also, it would make sense to filter the list for IP-enabled adapters first.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking on google before and nothing was working. I didn't realize that it had so many elements to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, .SetTcpipNetbios(2) does not work when the network adapter does not currently have an active network connection (it returns 84, “IP not enabled on adapter”), so it is impossible to disable NetBIOS this way before connecting to the network. Does anyone know another way which would work even before the network connection is established?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to set the configuration of NetBIOS on an adapter that has no connection, you can change the settings in the registry instead of directly using SetTcpIPNetbios.

I iterate through each of the adapter ports (I have 16) and then turn NetBIOS off on all of them:

```
$i = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\netbt\Parameters\interfaces'  
Get-ChildItem $i | ForEach-Object {  
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "$i\$($_.pschildname)" -name NetBiosOptions -value 2
}
```

Comment: That was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

From other answers and comment about, I use this as one line command to disable NetBIOS:

`(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IpEnabled="true").SetTcpipNetbios(2)`

Comment: This works as confirmed with the command `ipconfig /all`.

Answer (score 2):

As [WMI v1 cmdlets were removed in PowerShell 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/breaking-changes-ps6#wmi-v1-cmdlets), the "modern way" to do this is through CIM cmdlets, with an example from [powershell.one](https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_networkadapterconfiguration-SetTcpipNetbios):

```
# define the arguments you want to submit to the method
# remove values that you do not want to submit
# make sure you replace values with meaningful content before running the code
# see section "Parameters" below for a description of each argument.
$arguments = @{
    TcpipNetbiosOptions = [UInt32](12345)  # replace 12345 with a meaningful value
}


# select the instance(s) for which you want to invoke the method
# you can use "Get-CimInstance -Query (ADD FILTER CLAUSE HERE!)" to safely play with filter clauses
# if you want to apply the method to ALL instances, remove "Where...." clause altogether.
$query = 'Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where (ADD FILTER CLAUSE HERE!)'
Invoke-CimMethod -Query $query -Namespace Root/CIMV2 -MethodName SetTcpipNetbios -Arguments $arguments |
Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name ReturnValueFriendly -Passthru -Value {
  switch ([int]$this.ReturnValue)
  {
        0        {'Successful completion, no reboot required'}
        1        {'Successful completion, reboot required'}
        64       {'Method not supported on this platform'}
        65       {'Unknown failure'}
        66       {'Invalid subnet mask'}
        67       {'An error occurred while processing an Instance that was returned'}
        68       {'Invalid input parameter'}
        69       {'More than 5 gateways specified'}
        70       {'Invalid IP  address'}
        71       {'Invalid gateway IP address'}
        72       {'An error occurred while accessing the Registry for the requested information'}
        73       {'Invalid domain name'}
        74       {'Invalid host name'}
        75       {'No primary/secondary WINS server defined'}
        76       {'Invalid file'}
        77       {'Invalid system path'}
        78       {'File copy failed'}
        79       {'Invalid security parameter'}
        80       {'Unable to configure TCP/IP service'}
        81       {'Unable to configure DHCP service'}
        82       {'Unable to renew DHCP lease'}
        83       {'Unable to release DHCP lease'}
        84       {'IP not enabled on adapter'}
        85       {'IPX not enabled on adapter'}
        86       {'Frame/network number bounds error'}
        87       {'Invalid frame type'}
        88       {'Invalid network number'}
        89       {'Duplicate network number'}
        90       {'Parameter out of bounds'}
        91       {'Access denied'}
        92       {'Out of memory'}
        93       {'Already exists'}
        94       {'Path, file or object not found'}
        95       {'Unable to notify service'}
        96       {'Unable to notify DNS service'}
        97       {'Interface not configurable'}
        98       {'Not all DHCP leases could be released/renewed'}
        100      {'DHCP not enabled on adapter'}
        default  {'Unknown Error '}
    }
}
```

Note: this needs to be run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to get the NetBIOS status of each network adapter with a non-null `TcpipNetbiosOptions` property:

`Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' | Where-Object -Property 'TcpipNetbiosOptions' -ne $null | Select-Object -Property @('ServiceName', 'Description', 'TcpipNetbiosOptions');`

For each network adapter, a value of `1` indicates that NetBIOS is enabled and a value of `2` indicates that NetBIOS is disabled.

Use the following command to disable NetBIOS for each network adapter with a non-null `TcpipNetbiosOptions` property:

`Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' | Where-Object -Property 'TcpipNetbiosOptions' -ne $null | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName 'SetTcpipNetbios' -Arguments @{ 'TcpipNetbiosOptions' = [UInt32](2) } -Confirm;`

The `-Confirm` parameter requires confirmation for each change, which is helpful if one has multiple network adapters and only wants to change the NetBIOS status for some of them. Remove the `-Confirm` parameter to simply disable NetBIOS for *all* of the previously shown network adapters and thereby make the process faster.

A list of `ReturnValue` values should be shown. A `ReturnValue` value of `0` indicates that the operation was successful. Run the first command again to confirm the NetBIOS status of each network adapter.

Official Microsoft Documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null
- https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object
- https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object
- https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance
- https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod
- https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration
- https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/settcpipnetbios-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration